Python Module not Found after pip install in VSCode
Installed a new fresh version of python and running into the following error in VS Code:
Here are the steps I have taken:

Create Virtual Environment and activate:



Create Test.py Script and Test out importing module. Not found... Though strangely it is predicted as I type?



I notice its underlined in yellow so need to install the module.
3.Install module using pip:

4.All seems successfully installed and yellow line goes away


Running Script I Still get the error:


No idea why.
I have removed the virtual environment and reinstalled. same with the modules but no change.
only thing I think is odd is that after removal it still predicts Matplotlib as in the first image... SO maybe it's getting confused in some way?

Check to make sure python is getting run with your venv. It looks like it is, but if it's not, that could definitely do it.

Please could you advise a command to check this.

answer provided however unsure why this works. Also presumably this means a different version of the module compatible with a different version of python has been installed.

Check the version by printing matplotlib.__version __

'python3 -m pip install matplotlib'

So did you need to execute your script with python3?

no, they just ran as expected. Interpreter was python3 but no changed in how I ran other than hitting the play button in the top right
